# DataGridView: CellEnter not displaying the correct RowCount

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I created a user control with datagridview and label that display the row count. On some of the projects where I used the control, I'm having issue with the CellEnter event where it is not displaying the correct row count. I placed the label.text in the CellEnter event so the label value can change based on the entered cell.

In one of my projects, I have buttons that work as tabs. When the form load, it is adding the new control and populate the data. When button is clicked, it will delete the existing control and add new control (I did this because for some reason the column from previous table stick in the dgv even though I already clear the datatable and set the datasource to nothing). For some of the tables that I binded to the datagridview, the rowcount on the CellEnter display 2 (allow add row is set to true) where as in the DataSourceChange or CellValidating, it is showing the correct number (ex. 664). This only happen on the first load, once moving to different cell, it shows correct value.

So here's the sequence when the form first loaded:
1. CellEnter (row count = 2)
2. DataSourceChanged (row count = 664)
3. CellValidating (row count = 664)
4. CellEnter (row count = 2)

Click button that load the same table as when the form first load:
1. CellEnter (row count = 2)
2. DataSourceChanged (row count = 664)

I tried to use the row count based on the value that I get from the DataSourceChange, but it will messed up the label value if the records get deleted or added.
Also tried to move the label to CellValidating, but it not always display the correct row (Ex: Click cell 664 and move to cell 659, the label still display the 664).
If adding `dgv1.dgvEditor.CurrentCell = dgv1.dgvEditor.Item("TAG_CODE", 1)` to PopulateCodesGrid, it will display the correct label, but when changing the row to 0, it ended up with 1 of 1.

```
Private Sub dgvEditor_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEditor.CellEnter
    If AllowUserToAddRow Then
        If dgvEditor.CurrentCell.RowIndex = dgvEditor.Rows(dgvEditor.NewRowIndex).Index Then
            NewRowIndex = dgvEditor.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            lblDataNav.Text = dgvEditor.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 & " of " & dgvEditor.RowCount
        ElseIf NewRowIndex <> -1 Then
            lblDataNav.Text = dgvEditor.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 & " of " & dgvEditor.RowCount - 1
        Else
            lblDataNav.Text = dgvEditor.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 & " of " & dgvEditor.RowCount - 1
        End If
    Else
        lblDataNav.Text = dgvEditor.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 & " of " & dgvEditor.RowCount
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub SystemAdminForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dgv1 = New SQLTableEditor.ctlTableEditor
    Me.Controls.Add(dgv1)
    dgv1.BringToFront()

    dgv1.Visible = True
    dgv1.Location = New Point(25, 115)
    dgv1.Size = New Size(722, 550)
    dgv1.HeaderLabelVisible = False
    dgv1.DataNavigatorVisible = True

    PopulateCodesGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub CodesTab_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CodesTab.Click
    'Button click
    If (dgv1 IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (Not dgv1.IsDisposed) Then dgv1.Dispose()

        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Select Case btn.Name
            Case "CodesTab"
                dgv1 = New SQLTableEditor.ctlTableEditor
                Me.Controls.Add(dgv1)
                dgv1.BringToFront()

                dgv1.Visible = True
                dgv1.Location = New Point(25, 115)
                dgv1.Size = New Size(722, 550)
                dgv1.HeaderLabelVisible = False
                dgv1.DataNavigatorVisible = True

                PopulateCodesGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateCodesGrid()
    Try

        Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(MAIN_CONN)
            connection.Open()
            Using dAdapt As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("spGetCodes", connection)

                Dim colCategory = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
                colCategory.DataPropertyName = "CATEGORY"
                colCategory.HeaderText = "Category"
                colCategory.Name = "CATEGORY"
                colCategory.Width = 150
                colCategory.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
                For Each item In viewModel.DefectCategoryDropDownList
                    colCategory.Items.Add(item.Value)
                Next

                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns.Add(colCategory)

                dgv1.AllowUserToAddRow = True
                dgv1.AllowUpdateEditRecord = True
                dgv1.AllowUserToDeleteRow = False
                dgv1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells

                dAdapt.Fill(dgv1.dTable)
                dgv1.BindingSrc.DataSource = dgv1.dTable
                dgv1.dgvEditor.DataSource = dgv1.BindingSrc

                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("TAG_CODE").DisplayIndex = 0
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("TAG_CODE").HeaderText = "CODE"
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("TAG_CODE").ReadOnly = True
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("PROBLEM").DisplayIndex = 1
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("PROBLEM").HeaderText = "Description"
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("CATEGORY").DisplayIndex = 2
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("INACTIVE_DATE").DisplayIndex = 3
                dgv1.dgvEditor.Columns("INACTIVE_DATE").HeaderText = "Inactive Date"

                RemoveHandler dgv1.InsertRecord, AddressOf RTCodesInsertRecord
                RemoveHandler dgv1.UpdateRecord, AddressOf RTCodesUpdateRecord
                RemoveHandler dgv1.CellDefaultValue, AddressOf CellDefaultValue
                RemoveHandler dgv1.CellClick, AddressOf DGV1CellClickEvent

                AddHandler dgv1.InsertRecord, AddressOf RTCodesInsertRecord
                AddHandler dgv1.UpdateRecord, AddressOf RTCodesUpdateRecord
                AddHandler dgv1.CellDefaultValue, AddressOf CellDefaultValue
                AddHandler dgv1.CellClick, AddressOf DGV1CellClickEvent

            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I expected the rowcount in the CellEnter to be 664, not 2. I had other programmer help me looking at my code, and couldn't figure it out either. Note that this only happen on some, some other table on that same project loads just fine.